# Output from the printf is different than specified in the FORMAT argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, printf

I'm a little confused, the output from the `printf` is different than specified in the `FORMAT` argument:

```
$ echo "$PWD_HASH"
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$ZLgRL2DZSKYUCzht$PaTcpkoOi6P6p9ItIjRTL00MCB/8IU.fJbGk9EO/LxUAgZwGASO6qXNSNSzxQRBGjNiPpiArgwOacZSG5A6FL1
$ PWD_JSON=$(printf '{"password": "%s"}' "$PWD_HASH")
$ echo "$PWD_JSON" 
"}password": "{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$ZLgRL2DZSKYUCzht$PaTcpkoOi6P6p9ItIjRTL00MCB/8IU.fJbGk9EO/LxUAgZwGASO6qXNSNSzxQRBGjNiPpiArgwOacZSG5A6FL1
```

How / why? How to get the desired output?

If I pass the string directly (not from the variable), then I get the expected output:

```
$ PWD_JSON=$(printf '{"password": "%s"}' '{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$ZLgRL2DZSKYUCzht$PaTcpkoOi6P6p9ItIjRTL00MCB/8IU.fJbGk9EO/LxUAgZwGASO6qXNSNSzxQRBGjNiPpiArgwOacZSG5A6FL1')
$ echo "$PWD_JSON"
{"password": "{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$ZLgRL2DZSKYUCzht$PaTcpkoOi6P6p9ItIjRTL00MCB/8IU.fJbGk9EO/LxUAgZwGASO6qXNSNSzxQRBGjNiPpiArgwOacZSG5A6FL1"}
```

---

Just to complement the accepted answer, here in my `PWD_HASH` I have output from the `docker exec -t`. Apparently line-endings used by `TTY` are `CRLF` (`\r\n`), hence the unexpected `\r`...

Comment: Downvoters please leave a comment.

Comment: How is it different? I tried to reproduce and got `{"password": "{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$ZLgRL2DZSKYUCzht$PaTcpkoOi6P6p9ItIjRTL00MCB/8IU.fJbGk9EO/LxUAgZwGASO6qXNSNSzxQRBGjNiPpiArgwOacZSG5A6FL1"}`, is this what you expect?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, this is what I expect, see the edit.

Comment: Side note: shell variable names should be lower-case. (there is a standard somewhere, it stops you colliding with environment variables).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable `PWD_HASH` contains a carriage return `\r` at the end of the string which moves the last two characters `"}` to the beginning of the output.

Example:

```
$ PWD_HASH='{SHA512-CRYPT}abcde'$'\r'
$ PWD_JSON=$(printf '{"password": "%s"}' "$PWD_HASH")
$ echo "$PWD_HASH"
{SHA512-CRYPT}abcde
$ echo "$PWD_JSON"
"}password": "{SHA512-CRYPT}abcde
$ echo "$PWD_JSON" | od -c
0000000   {   "   p   a   s   s   w   o   r   d   "   :       "   {   S
0000020   H   A   5   1   2   -   C   R   Y   P   T   }   a   b   c   d
0000040   e  \r   "   }  \n
0000045
```

Comment: Also, `printf -v PWD_JSON 'format string' values` (as a convenience in place of an awkward command substitution).